# Android ActionBarSherlock Maven - No resources found

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-resources, android-maven-plugin

I have been trying to add ActionBarSherlock Maven dependecy on my project and i'm getting some problems. When i use ABS themes like:

```
<style name="AppThemeCustomizada" parent="@style/Sherlock.__Theme.DarkActionBar">
```

I get the following error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Sherlock.__Theme.DarkActionBar'.
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>RunasProject</groupId>
<artifactId>RunasProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Runas</name>
<dependencies>      

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>8</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have tried many suggestion on net, but i could not solve the problem. ABS classes work fine, but styles don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the packaging of your project to apk and use the Android Maven Plugin. Your configuration is mixing setup from the Android Maven Plugin into the Compiler plugin. That wont work. Check out the sample applications (including an ABS demo) of the Android Maven Plugin.